# put a button with maps fragment in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I am implementing google map api which shows device's current location and i want to put a button in the layout just below the map fragment , which will initiate the next action when clicked, but when i drag and drop the button on layout it cannot be seen, neither the code for button is visible in xml file,

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="250dpi"
tools:context="com.example.hitesh.cspvisual.MapsActivity" />
```

as you can see fragment layout-height is 250dpi hence there is some space remaining below fragment and i want to put the button there.
what should i do?
thank you for your suggestions

Comment: embed the map fragment and button in a RelativeLayout

Comment: One of the best things about Android is how easy it is to **not** use the drag and drop editor- get used to using the XML directly, and just switching to the design to see your changes, and you'll become quite confident quite quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Try This

**I think you need to implement like while you are using map**

---

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<EditText
android:id="@+id/edt_pickup"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:hint="Enter Your Pick Up Location"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="55dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/edt_pickup"
    android:text="Pick up"
    android:id="@+id/btn_pick"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
<EditText
 android:layout_below="@id/edt_pickup"
 android:id="@+id/drop"
 android:layout_margin="5dp"
 android:hint="Enter Your Drop location"
 android:layout_width="250dp"
 android:layout_height="55dp" />

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_marginTop="155dp"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.immanent.implementation_maps.MapsActivity" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn_drop"
    android:text="Drop"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/drop"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/drop"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/drop"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/drop" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.hitesh.cspvisual.MapsActivity" >

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/map"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="250dpi"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a wrapper for the fragment and the button for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        tools:context="com.example.hitesh.cspvisual.MapsActivity" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:text="Button 1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely this would work for you

```
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:gravity="bottom">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_selectdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:alpha="0.5"
            android:background="@drawable/drawable_selectstop"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:paddingRight="50dp"
            android:text="Select Date"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Rosario I will remember in future.